# C/C++: Is it possible to configure the Eclipse project settings to accept void pointer without casting for all Linux distros

Tags: c++, c, linux, eclipse

In some variants of Linux distro, the C/C++ compiler accepts the conversion of some type (e.g. bool) to void pointer (void*) without casting like below but some of them will throw a compilation error:

```
void* do_something()
{
    return true;
}
```

I am using the Eclipse to build the project but not allowed to modify the code due to some reason. Is it possible to configure the Eclipse project settings to accept void pointer without casting for all Linux distros?

### Edit 1

For those who give negative comments regarding the bad written language, I would like to clarify that the code is not written by me and I have explained I am not allowed to modify the code. So please kindly understand my situation and I would like to compile the project in Ubuntu that I am working on.

If the answer is not possible, please simply say 'NO'.

Comment: That conversion is not valid in C or C++. Even if it was, that code snippet is not. I don’t know what the rules are for C/C++.

Comment: If you should actually find a compiler that accepts that snippet, you know which one to avoid...

Comment: @PeteBecker I understand it not valid and you should do something like `return (void*)true` but as explained I am not allowed to modify the source code.

Comment: GCC (C compiler) ought to compile `#include <stdbool.h> void* do_something() { return true; }`, but the compiler will whine like a mule. And it's right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments above, the answer is **NO**. And ideally I need to fix the above code with proper casting (if I am allowed to do so).

Comment: I have seen some compilers that could quietly automatically cast size_t, ssize_t, and any equivalent types to void *.  Note that I'm not saying unsigned int and int there because that's hardware dependent - it's basically whatever type the system uses for pointers.  I am not aware of any compiler that would let you get away with trying to convert a float or char to a void*, or vis versa.  Which was big issue when someone decided I needed to port some ancient code from the 16 bit days that abused that sort of a thing.  And of course used no typedefs and depended on some shorts remaining short.

Answer (score -1):

```
void* do_something()
    return true
```

This is neither valid C nor valid C++.

And in both languages doing that would be a terrible idea. A `true` value should
not be casted/converted to any pointer, it is not going to be valid value. Don't
do that.

Comment: I understand this is not acceptable but it's not my code. And I have explained that I am not allowed to modify the code

Comment: @chesschi you are not allowed to modify the code? What does that mean? Regardless, no C nor C++ compiler should be able to compile this, because this is syntax error.

Comment: Please see my edit to explain why I am not allowed to modify the source code. Yes there are C/C++ compiler in some variants of Linux distro accept that, and that was my pain to address it.

Comment: @chesschi I seriously doubt that. Which compiler compiles that without error?

Comment: I am not too sure but I think it's the compiler comes from old version of CentOS

Comment: @chesschi I don't believe that. That is not valid syntax, semicolons are missing, `return` belongs to what? There are so many syntax errors there, I seriously doubt that any compiler (even older ones) compiles this without showing you errors.

Comment: Well spotted and I have added back the semi-colon but there exists some compilers that can compile this.